# How can I redirect https to another https in Apache-Bitnami?

Tags: apache, redirect, https, dns

Good Morning,

I have the following problem and I do not know how to solve it.

I have on a Linux machine, a Wordpress installation made with Bitnami. The problem I'm having is that I do not know how to redirect an https domain to another https domain with SSL. More information:

- I have a domain "www . xxx. com" with security certificate
- I have two other domains "www. xxx. es" and "www .xxx .net" without a security certificate.

At Apache level, I have already made the configuration so that I can redirect the following requests:

```
http://www. xxx .es -> https://www. xxx .com
http://www. xxx .net -> https://www. xxx .com
http://www. xxx .com -> https://www. xxx. com
```

I can not configure is that I redirect the following requests:

```
https://www. xxx .es -> https://www. xxx .com
https://www. xxx .net -> https://www. xxx .com
```

Here is my vhost configuration:

```
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfVersion>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/htdocs"

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^xxx .com$
  RewriteRule ^ https://www. xxx .com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

  <Directory "/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Default SSL Virtual Host configuration.

<IfModule !ssl_module>
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>

Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH !RC4"
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/htdocs"


  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/conf/www.opein.com_2019.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/conf/www.opein.com_2019.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/conf/www.opein.com_2019.ca"

  <Directory "/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Bitnami applications that uses virtual host configuration
Include "/opt/lampstack-7.1.14-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf"
```

Comment: In order to respond to https:// requests for a domain, you need to have the certificate for that domain name (you need it even if you only want to do the redirect!). If you think about it, it makes sense, why would my browser trust your redirect if you don't have the certificate.